# How can I set ngrok on Vapor to work locally with an owned domain?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ngrok, vapor

When setting up ngrok on my Vapor server application, using a docker container, I cannot manage to create a secure web connection using a custom domain that I own.

I would like to use my `docker-compose.yml` file to read the `ngrok.yml` one with the setup, but I have had a better result using the command line.

Let say the owned domain is: `api.personal_domain.com`.
The CNAME DNS record from ngrok.com is added to my domain provider.

I run this command to start the "secure web connection" on localhost.

```bash
$ docker run -it -e NGROK_AUTHTOKEN=<NGROK_PERSONAL_TOKEN> ngrok/ngrok http https://127.0.0.1:8080 --domain=api.personal_domain.com
```

But still a failure occurs with a `404 Not Found`. I can see that the server is not receiving the request.

**This is the configuration of the postgres data base made on the Vapor application:**

```swift
app.databases.use(.postgres(
  hostname: "api.personal_domain.com",
  port: 5433,
  username: "user_stackoverflow",
  password: "password_stackoverflow",
  database: "personal_domain_db_develop"
), as: .psql)
```

**This is the setup in the `docker-compose.yml` file:**

```yaml
ngrok:
  image: ngrok:latest
  restart: unless-stopped
  command:
    - "start"
    - "--all"
    - "--config"
    - "/etc/ngrok.yml"
  volumes:
    - ./ngrok.yml:/etc/ngrok.yml
  ports:
    - 4040:
```

**And the `ngrok.yml` file is set this way:**

```yaml
version: "2"
authtoken: <NGROK_PERSONAL_TOKEN>
tunnels:
 server:
  addr: 5433
  proto: http
  host_header: localhost
  domain: api.personal_domain.com
```

From there, I run `$ docker compose up` in the Terminal but an error occurs.

```bash
[+] Running 1/1
 ✘ ngrok Error                                                                            2.1s 
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for ngrok, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I would like to have a secure HTTPS connection when developing my server on localhost using docker.

How can I setup the ngrok tunnel properly for my Vapor application to run locally on a secure web connection?

Comment: Try `ngrok/ngrok` for the image in `docker-compose.yml`. Also, focus on one issue per post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From "[Using ngrok with Docker Compose](https://ngrok.com/docs/using-ngrok-with/docker/)", try and use a `docker-compose.yml` file like:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  vapor:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user_stackoverflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password_stackoverflow
      POSTGRES_DB: personal_domain_db_develop
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  ngrok:
    image: ngrok/ngrok:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - vapor
    command:
      - "start"
      - "--all"
      - "--config"
      - "/etc/ngrok.yml"
    volumes:
      - ./ngrok.yml:/etc/ngrok.yml
```

With a `ngrok.yml` set to use an HTTPS connection:

```yaml
version: "2"
authtoken: <NGROK_PERSONAL_TOKEN>
tunnels:
  server:
    addr: 8080
    proto: https
    host_header: localhost
    domain: api.personal_domain.com
```

Update your Vapor app to listen on all interfaces (`app.http.server.configuration.hostname = "0.0.0.0"`): that should be in  `configure.swift` file in the `Sources/App` directory.

```swift
import Vapor
import Fluent
import FluentPostgresDriver

public func configure(_ app: Application) throws {
    app.http.server.configuration.hostname = "0.0.0.0"

    // Other configurations, like database, middleware, etc.

}
```

And update your database connection configuration in the Vapor app to use the correct hostname ("db") and port (5432):

```swift
app.databases.use(.postgres(
  hostname: "db",
  port: 5432,
  username: "user_stackoverflow",
  password: "password_stackoverflow",
  database: "personal_domain_db_develop"
), as: .psql)
```

https://api.personal_domain.com should then be available after `docker-compose up`.

Answer (score 3):

PM from ngrok here. As mentioned by @john-hanley, you should be using `image: ngrok/ngrok:latest` in your docker compose file. Here is a link to the ngrok documentation page for [using ngrok with Docker](https://ngrok.com/docs/using-ngrok-with/docker/).

Also, I noticed that in your first docker command, you are using port 4040, which happens to be a port that ngrok uses by default for a local inspection interface and agent API. Based on your configuration file, the docker command you need is:

`docker run --net=host -it -e NGROK_AUTHTOKEN=xyz ngrok/ngrok:latest http 5433 --domain api.personal_domain.com`

If you are on a Mac or Windows machine, the command would be:

`docker run -it -e NGROK_AUTHTOKEN=xyz ngrok/ngrok:latest http host.docker.internal:5433 --domain api.personal_domain.com`

Comment: When setting up the correct `ngrok/ngrok:latest` image, it works. But I am still failing on running the data base correctly and have a `502 Bad Gateway` response. How to setup the `docker-compose.yml` and `ngrok.yml` files in order to create a `https` connection with my custom domain?